# some question of quasi compactness of schemes

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Using affine scheme is quasi compact, I want to show that schmes is quasi compact if it is a finte affine cover. is it possible? if possible, I want to proof.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**: Given an open covering $\mathfrak U$ of the scheme $X,$ which we assume is a finite union of quasi-compact (open affine) schemes $X_i,$ we know that a finite subcovering $\mathfrak U_i\subseteq\mathfrak U$ suffices to cover $X_i$ for each $i.$